# How To Say "-able" in Latin

Tags: classical-latin, word-request, adjective, conjugation, participle

Is it possible to use something similar to the English suffix "-able" to show that the action described can be done by someone or something? If not, what phrases do you suggest to use in its place?

Comment: Are you aware that the English suffix -able is borrowed directly from the Latin -abilis, with the same meaning?

Comment: Related question on Linguistics SE: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/is-the-word-e-able-related-to-the-suffix-e-able

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As brianpck mentioned, the English suffix "-able" is borrowed from Latin. The rules for applying it in Latin are more transparent than the English alteration between "-able" and "-ible". *EDIT: And are actually even easier, now that I think about it.*

- First, choose your stem.

  - If the verb has a fourth principal part (supine) ending in *-tus*, remove the *-tus* and use that stem: *amō, amātus* > *amā-*
  - If it has a fourth principal part not ending in *-tus*, add an *-i* and use that stem: *rideō, rīsus* > *rīsi-*
  - Otherwise (e.g. *posse*), use the present infinitive stem (*poss-*)
- If this stem already ends in *-bi*, attach *-lis*: *habi-* > *habilis*, *nūbi* > *nūbilis* > nubile.

  - These would originally have been *habibilis* and *nūbibilis*; the *-bibi-* was reduced to *-bi-* by haplogy.
- Otherwise, attach *-bilis*.

All of the resulting adjectives are regular two-termination thirds: *-ilis*, *-ilis*, *-ile*.

My previous, overly complicated, explanation:

- If the present stem ends in a vowel (including *v* and *j*), add *-bilis*: *mov-* > *mōbilis* > mobile

  - This can cause diphthongs to contract (ov → ō), since they're followed by a consonant
  - Usually vowel-stem verbs are obvious, but some are trickier; the stem of *fleō* is *fle-* rather than *fl-* (and thus it becomes *flēbilis*)
- If the verb is first-conjugation, attach *-ābilis* to the present stem: *am-* > *amābilis*, *dūr-* > *dūrābilis* > durable.
- Otherwise, attach *-ibilis*...

  - If the fourth principal part ends with *-tus*, or there is no fourth part, use the present stem: *crēd-* > *crēdibilis* > credible, *poss-* > *possibilis* > possible
  - Otherwise, use the supine stem: *rīd-* > *rīsibilis* > risible, *vid-* > *vīsibilis* > visible

<s>There are also a few exceptions to these rules: for instance, *stō, stāre* > *stăbilis* rather than **stābilis*. But **stābilis* would still be easily understood.</s>

(The more complicated rules worked, but there's no reason to memorize them if you already know the supine stem. Using the supine also eliminates "irregularities" like *stăbilis* from *stō, stătus* and *flēbilis* from *fleō, flētus*.)

Comment: Good answer! Two comments: (1) Are there exceptions to your rule? *Facilis* = "doable"? (2) Is "haplogy" an intentional pun?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I was going to ask about exceptions too: I can think of a few. For instance, by these rules, it would be *utor* -> *usibilis*.

Comment: @brianpck Hmm... Does *fertilis* come from *ferre* this way or is it a different derivative altogether? I'm trying to figure out if one should use the present stem as suggested by *utilis* (not *usi(bi)lis*).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta (2) is intentional, though I can change it if it's actually confusing. (1) probably though I can't think of many (brianpck's *ūtibilis* is a good catch); I feel like present stem + *-ilis* has a slightly different meaning than supine stem + *-ibilis* though I'm not sure exactly how or why (need to search more).

Comment: (2) It's not confusing. I was just curious. (1) It could be that different stems and slightly different suffixes have a difference in meaning, but I'm not sure if that's meaningful. Your rule is an excellent rule of thumb, but I'm not sure how far its validity extends. (3) It'd be interesting to know what grammars say about this.

Comment: @Draconis I got a good chuckle out of "haplogy," too, so no need to change it in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

The English suffix "-able/-ible" comes directly from Latin *-abilis/-ibilis*.

A search for [Latin words ending in *-bilis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=bilis&lang=la) returns **737 results**, of which the first few are:

- *abominabilis*
- *accensibilis*
- *acceptabilis*
- *accessibilis*
- *accusabilis*
- *adfabilis*
- *adibilis*
- *adjutabilis*
- *admirabilis*

Comment: Would you consider *facilis* from *facere* the same derivative, even though there is no B (not *facibilis*)?

Comment: I think you're right: Priscian has a [discussion about it](https://books.google.com/books?id=H-gxoTF2Oz4C&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132), also citing the examples *docilis* and *utilis*. Interestingly, *utibilis* is also attested: I'm not sure if this was just to avoid the perceived dissonance (if that's the word) of -ibili- or if there is some other rule at work.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, semantically the two are close or maybe even indistinguishable, but technically they're not the same suffix, since they are two different forms and are not allomorphs. Another such pair are *flexilis / flexibilis*.

Answer (score 4):

This might have been better as a comment, but I think it worth an answer to link generally to other answers and comments.

The University of British Columbia publishes an excellent introduction to this general kind of thing for both Latin and Greek at  https://pressbooks.bccampus.ca/greeklatinroots/front-matter/preface/, where the linked page has a table of further linked contents. Chapter 5 is on 'Turning Latin Nouns into Adjectives', within which para. 34 discusses adjective-forming suffixes in English, while 35 and onwards give examples of endings and their derivation (including -*ilis*, -*arius* and -*osus*.)